# Не подключается SVG спрайт

Tags: svg, объекты

Пробую подключить SVG спрайт с помощью object, но он не подгружает svg файл и use не срабатывают. Я уже совсем отчаялся. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с таким или просто ткнет меня носом, где я косяк допустил.

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/images/sprite.svg">
</object>
```

подключаю в body.

```
<svg>
     <use xlink:href="images/sprite.svg#cloth"/></use>
</svg>
```

такая конструкция не срабатывает

А может что-то в самом спрайте не так сделал. Если что - вот ссыль http://dropmefiles.com/0q1J8

Comment: не отчаивайтесь. У всех, кто хотел подключить спрайт, рано или поздно получилось. Дайте код спрайта/ ,Cо ссылки, которую вы дали, я не смог взять Разместите, на https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8nzcpa2x/

Comment: заглядывайте почаще, обязательно дам ответ

Comment: хорошо, спасибо большое

Comment: ошибки нашел, их было 3 штуки. Уточняющий вопрос, чтобы сделать всё под ключ. Какого размера иконки вы хотите получить в HTML после подключения спрайта 512х512?:

Comment: в идеале 74х74 пикселя

Comment: тогда я подправлю ваш спрайт. Так как происходит многократное масштабирование, вам будет трудно разобраться. Постараюсь упростить всё до минимума

Comment: Получилось переделать спрайт? И где я успел напортачить?

Comment: получилось исправить ошибки. В Firefox работает всё как надо, но в Chrome не работает спрайт. Ищу причину. Для меня самого, это большая загадка на настоящий момент.  В любом случае на финише, в ответе напишу всё подробно.

Comment: я так понял не получилось сделать спрайт жизнеспособным

Comment: тут дело оказалось значительно серьезней. Время нехорошее сейчас, с этими закрытиями сетей по маскам. У меня начали отваливаться старые по спрайтам топики, которые раньше были работоспособные. Видимо появилось какое-то несоответствие с правилами безопасности `Chrome` при работе с файлами. Остается только ждать, когда всё устаканится

Comment: могу предложить решение с `<img>` добавлением `svg в html`, но нужно тогда будет разбивать svg спрайт на отдельные файлы по иконкам, что конечно намного хуже, чем добавления спрайта

Comment: с img я управился сам - нужен был конкретно спрайт для уменьшения количества запросов на сервер. Спасибо за содействие.

Comment: и для меня эта тема важна и интересна и для меня, всё равно иногда заглядывай, надеюсь на лучшее